# How to add a groupby to a view query

Tags: views

I have a view and I need to add a groupby at the end of the SQL query but, for some bugged module the interface do not save the 'Grouping field Nr.' option and I don't know how to achieve this view -.-

[image: view page]

```
SELECT DISTINCT taxonomy_term_data.tid AS tid,
  field_testata_taxonomy_term_data.product_id AS field_testata_taxonomy_term_data_product_id,
  field_magazine_commerce_product.nid AS field_magazine_commerce_product_nid,
  field_magazine_commerce_product.LANGUAGE AS field_magazine_commerce_product_language,
  taxonomy_term_data.NAME AS taxonomy_term_data_name,
  taxonomy_term_data.vid AS taxonomy_term_data_vid,
  taxonomy_vocabulary.machine_name AS taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name,
  'taxonomy_term' AS field_data_field_mondi_azzurra_taxonomy_term_entity_type,
  'taxonomy_term' AS field_data_field_avatar_taxonomy_term_entity_type,
  'taxonomy_term' AS field_data_field_logo_slider_taxonomy_term_entity_type,
  'taxonomy_term' AS field_data_field_image_taxonomy_term_entity_type,
  'commerce_product' AS field_data_field_image_commerce_product_entity_type,
  'taxonomy_term' AS field_data_field_call_to_action_taxonomy_term_entity_type
FROM {taxonomy_term_data} taxonomy_term_data
  LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_testata} field_data_field_testata ON taxonomy_term_data.tid = field_data_field_testata.field_testata_tid AND (field_data_field_testata.entity_type = 'commerce_product' AND field_data_field_testata.deleted = '0')
  LEFT JOIN {commerce_product} field_testata_taxonomy_term_data ON ield_data_field_testata.entity_id = field_testata_taxonomy_term_data.product_id
  LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_magazine} field_testata_taxonomy_term_data__field_data_field_magazine ON field_testata_taxonomy_term_data.product_id = field_testata_taxonomy_term_data__field_data_field_magazine.field_magazine_product_id
  LEFT JOIN {node} field_magazine_commerce_product ON field_testata_taxonomy_term_data__field_data_field_magazine.entity_id = field_magazine_commerce_product.nid
  LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_vocabulary} taxonomy_vocabulary ON taxonomy_term_data.vid = taxonomy_vocabulary.vid
WHERE (((taxonomy_vocabulary.machine_name IN ('testate'))))
```

I have to pick the last node connected to the taxonomy term [connected to another taxonomy term filtered by context] and now for each term and I have all the taxonomy-node coupple.

How can I achieve this?

There is a way to add 'Groupby tid' at the end of the query? Or I have to build the query diffrently?

UPDATE:
If I active 'Use aggregation' I have this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT field_data_field_avatar. AS field_data_field_avatar_, 
field_data_field_logo_slider. AS field_data_field_logo_slider_, field_data_field_image. AS field_data_field_image_, field_magazine_commerce_product.nid AS field_magazine_commerce_product_nid, field_magazine_commerce_product.language AS field_magazine_commerce_product_language, field_data_field_call_to_action.field_call_to_action_value AS field_data_field_call_to_action_field_call_to_action_value, taxonomy_term_data.name AS taxonomy_term_data_name, taxonomy_term_data.vid AS taxonomy_term_data_vid, taxonomy_term_data.tid AS tid_1, taxonomy_vocabulary.machine_name AS taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name, COUNT(DISTINCT field_data_field_mondi_azzurra.field_mondi_azzurra_tid) AS field_data_field_mondi_azzurra_field_mondi_azzurra_tid, COUNT(DISTINCT field_data_field_mondi_azzurra.delta) AS field_data_field_mondi_azzurra_delta, COUNT(DISTINCT field_data_field_mondi_azzurra.language) AS field_data_field_mondi_azzurra_language, COUNT(DISTINCT field_data_field_mondi_azzurra.bundle) AS field_data_field_mondi_azzurra_bundle, MIN(taxonomy_term_data.tid) AS tid, 'taxonomy_term' AS field_data_field_avatar_taxonomy_term_entity_type, 'taxonomy_term' AS field_data_field_logo_slider_taxonomy_term_entity_type, 'taxonomy_term' AS field_data_field_image_taxonomy_term_entity_type, MIN(field_testata_taxonomy_term_data.product_id) AS field_testata_taxonomy_term_data_product_id, 'commerce_product' AS field_data_field_image_commerce_product_entity_type, MAX(field_testata_taxonomy_term_data__field_data_field_image.bundle) AS field_testata_taxonomy_term_data__field_data_field_image_bun, 'taxonomy_term' AS field_data_field_call_to_action_taxonomy_term_entity_type
FROM 
{taxonomy_term_data} taxonomy_term_data
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_testata} field_data_field_testata ON taxonomy_term_data.tid = field_data_field_testata.field_testata_tid AND (field_data_field_testata.entity_type = 'commerce_product' AND field_data_field_testata.deleted = '0')
LEFT JOIN {commerce_product} field_testata_taxonomy_term_data ON field_data_field_testata.entity_id = field_testata_taxonomy_term_data.product_id
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_magazine} field_testata_taxonomy_term_data__field_data_field_magazine ON field_testata_taxonomy_term_data.product_id = field_testata_taxonomy_term_data__field_data_field_magazine.field_magazine_product_id
LEFT JOIN {node} field_magazine_commerce_product ON field_testata_taxonomy_term_data__field_data_field_magazine.entity_id = field_magazine_commerce_product.nid
LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_vocabulary} taxonomy_vocabulary ON taxonomy_term_data.vid = taxonomy_vocabulary.vid
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_mondi_azzurra} field_data_field_mondi_azzurra ON taxonomy_term_data.tid = field_data_field_mondi_azzurra.entity_id AND (field_data_field_mondi_azzurra.entity_type = 'taxonomy_term' AND field_data_field_mondi_azzurra.deleted = '0')
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_avatar} field_data_field_avatar ON taxonomy_term_data.tid = field_data_field_avatar.entity_id AND (field_data_field_avatar.entity_type = 'taxonomy_term' AND field_data_field_avatar.deleted = '0')
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_logo_slider} field_data_field_logo_slider ON taxonomy_term_data.tid = field_data_field_logo_slider.entity_id AND (field_data_field_logo_slider.entity_type = 'taxonomy_term' AND field_data_field_logo_slider.deleted = '0')
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_image} field_data_field_image ON taxonomy_term_data.tid = field_data_field_image.entity_id AND (field_data_field_image.entity_type = 'taxonomy_term' AND field_data_field_image.deleted = '0')
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_image} field_testata_taxonomy_term_data__field_data_field_image ON field_testata_taxonomy_term_data.product_id = field_testata_taxonomy_term_data__field_data_field_image.entity_id AND (field_testata_taxonomy_term_data__field_data_field_image.entity_type = 'commerce_product' AND field_testata_taxonomy_term_data__field_data_field_image.deleted = '0')
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_call_to_action} field_data_field_call_to_action ON taxonomy_term_data.tid = field_data_field_call_to_action.entity_id AND (field_data_field_call_to_action.entity_type = 'taxonomy_term' AND field_data_field_call_to_action.deleted = '0')
WHERE (( (taxonomy_vocabulary.machine_name IN  ('testate')) ))
GROUP BY field_data_field_avatar_taxonomy_term_entity_type, field_data_field_logo_slider_taxonomy_term_entity_type, field_data_field_image_taxonomy_term_entity_type, field_data_field_image_commerce_product_entity_type, field_data_field_call_to_action_taxonomy_term_entity_type
```

and this SQL error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS field_data_field_avatar_, field_data_field_logo_slider. AS field_data_field_l' at line 1
```

As you can see this query is not correctly written by drupal: there are some dots after the fields name in the frist part of the query..

Do you think I can fix this Views's core error?

Comment: If you suspect the module is buggy, you should file a bug report, which sort of makes the question off-topic. In the mean time though, you could hook_views_alter the query.

Comment: I tryed to build an hook_views_alter() but it do not seem to work. I use add_groupby($clause) but the result just work before the groupby add..

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable aggregation under *Advanced > Use aggregation*. You can then select how you want your data grouped using the settings under **Fields**, **Sort criteria** and **Filter criteria**.

[image: Views screen grab of field aggregation settings]

Comment: If I try to use aggregation the query return me an SQL error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS field_data_field_avatar_, field_data_field_logo_slider. AS field_data_field_l' at line 1. I tryed that.

Comment: Try turning on the SQL view and debugging it using SQL directly for comparision. You should be able to detect the cause of the error. Possibly a missing field or a grouping in the wrong place. Visit Views settings http://example.com/admin/structure/views/settings and check the `Show the SQL query` checkbox under `Live Preview settings`

Comment: I have SQL debbugging already active but i didn't read the query with the aggregation mode on.. question updated

Comment: I think you need to try getting the query working how you want it in SQL first then try any track down what you have done incorrectly in Views that causes a bad query. I've noticed a couple of times that unless you have specified a Sort criteria the query will always fail. Try sorting on term ID or something. If that stops the query from failing then you can continue to debug.